# Derivative of a polynomial with 2 variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have the following polynomial $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by:
\begin{equation}
f(x_{1},x_{2})=3x_{1}^{m}x_{2}^{n}+x_{1}^{k}
\end{equation}
for some nonnegative integers $m,n$, and $k$. Since $f$ is a polynomial we know that is is differentiable. The question then asks me to give
\begin{equation}
(Df):\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \text{Lin}(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathbb{R}).
\end{equation}

I understand how do this type of question for a polynomial with one variable. For example $f(x)=3x^{n}$ is differentiable with $f^{\prime}(x)=3nx^{n-1}$. So therefore
\begin{equation}
(Df):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \text{Lin}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \text{ is given by } x\mapsto(h\mapsto3nx^{n-1}h)
\end{equation}
But I am struggling with figuring out how to do it for two variables. Of which variable am I supposed to take the derivative? I tried taking the derivative of both $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ respectively and then taking the sum, but there is no logic behind that decision so I don't think I am on the right track here. Could someone please explain to me how I should approach such a question for a multivariable function?

Comment: Hint: Elements of $\text{Lin}(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathbb{R})$ are $1 \times 2$ matrices (assuming you treat $\mathbb R$ as column vectors).

Comment: You should closely examine the definition of what you mean by the multivariable derivative map. In this case, the derivative will be a vector (or rather, a 2x1 matrix, as all linear operators are matrices). You take partial derivatives with respect to both variables.